# How to identify the source of a #NAME? error in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

My LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet contains the following formula:

```
=IF(D8=0,'',C8*D8/B8)
```

If B8, C8, and D8 all have values, then this works. But if they are empty it doesn't work, I get a `#NAME?` error code.

In this particular case, all I want is a version of the formula that works for empty and full input cells (I think you can see the intent), but I would also like, in the general case, to interrogate LibreOffice and ask it which part of the formula contains an invalid name reference.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part 1: Formula that works for empty cells**

Use double quotes: `=IF(D8=0,"",C8*D8/B8)`

A text string in LibreOffice Calc (and Microsoft Excel) is specified with double quotes. The `#NAME?` error in your formula is from trying to display `''` which is an invalid identifier or value.

- The formula `=''` results in a `#NAME?` error.
- The formula `=""` displays a blank cell.

**Part 2: Determine Invalid Part Of Formula**

Click the Function Wizard icon ([image]) to open the Function Wizard for the cell.

[image: Function Wizard Icon- Screenshot]

In this case, the error is indicated by the red circle on the `''` line.

[image]